# Cannot add Amazon Banner Links in Joomla Site

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jhtml

I am brand new to Joomla and it appears that it does not allow JavaScript codes to run by default. I am running my website on the latest version (3.10). I have looked all around the internet, disabled all editor options as suggested, however to no avail. Wondering if there is a way to enable it without installing any additional module/plugin. From old references, something similar to adding a custom HTML/JavaScript is needed. I need to be able to place Amazon/Google advertisements on my site.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: Depending on your site template you may be able to ass custom js/css in the template settings (`Extensions -> Templates -> Styles -> [template name]`)

Comment: @jonboy thank you for responding. I was able to add a custom JS on the location as you suggested. However, (i) I am unable to call it inside a module, (ii) I would not know even if i was successfully able to call it on the page coz no matter what nothing appears on the module when it is published.

Comment: @ManishKYadav You didn't mention you wanted to include the code inside a module, in that case my suggestion won't work as it will be included in the `<head>` of each page. I don't know any way of doing this without installing a third party plugin, or creating your own custom module https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module. Is there any reason why you can't install a third party plugin? Would make the process much easier.

Comment: @jonboy i tried a few plugins but to no avail. A few of them needed a paid 'pro' version to unlock features to enable them but I am not in a situation where i can use a paid version. Also, with the limited features that were enabled, i still could not see a thing after saving the modules.

Comment: @jonboy I tried Sourcerer but it says the pro version is needed to add JavaScript :-( 
The reason I was looking for a free plugin to use, or possibly, do it natively, without any plugin at all.

Comment: @jonboy I tried looking for it but could not get one by the exact same name. It would really be helpful if you could post the link of the plugin. I would test it and let you know of the results. Even if you won't be able to help further, I think I would still be grateful to you for the time you spent answering the question. I highly appreciate it dear friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129007/discussion-between-jonboy-and-manish-k-yadav).